# Can I claim deductions for my wife as a non-resident alien in the US?

Tags: usa, taxes, non-residents, california

My Situation:

- Both my wife (J2) and I (J1) are currently in US.
- We do not fullfill the physical presence test, nor will we fullfill it at the end of the tax year.

When I received my first pay check my allowance was set to `0` and I was stated as `single` for both federal and state (CA for the case it matters) taxes. As a non-resident alien I'm maximum allowed `1`/`Single` as far as I understood from the [W4](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf), same goes for the state withholding.

This question concerns the end of the year tax return. According to [this](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Nonresident-Alien---Figuring-Your-Tax) we cannot file jointly. My question is however if I can claim deduction on her behalf. Or in other words if we look at [this table](http://www.form1040nr.com/taxrates2.php) if we both file as single or both as married. I'm interested in both the federal and the state case.

Bonus question: Would the situation change if she would be working?

Comment: Check if your university has any tax assistance programmes.  If your wife never worked (never had a work permit, which would be necessary for J2), she likely doesn't even have to file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tax witholding.  More appropriate for money.SE

Comment: @Kuruma. Thank you for your comment. The question that borders me is if I can deduct my wife at then end of the year from my salary. My past experience with Visa/SSN/... questions is that they are not terribly well informed themselves.

Comment: @Karlson. While I agree that I could have also been posted at money.SE I still think this is the right side for it, since this question only arises when you move into a new Country (paying income taxes under a visa status).

Comment: @Karlson I agree with magu_, this question has little to do with finances and everything to do with the significant difficulty caused to foreigners by the USA's uniquely confusing and complicated tax rules.

Comment: Seems to be on-topic on both sites to me. Not sure which is "more appropriate", but that's irrelevant to the question of close voting.

Comment: Though your answer (for federal taxes, at least) seems to be on the same IRS page you link to when asking your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot deduct your wife, she's not an object and you didn't pay for her.

With regards to dependents - you claim exemptions, not deduct them. But since you're a non-resident, you cannot claim exemption for your wife. You can only claim for yourself.

There are some specific exceptions to this general rule listed on [this IRS site](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Aliens---How-Many-Exemptions-Can-Be-Claimed%3F).

In California, if you file a resident return (form 540) - you can claim exemption for your wife as well. Pay attention: California defines who can file non-resident returns differently from the Federal government.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. This seems to be a bit discriminating but nothing I can do here I guess. Addressing the other part of your question, I changed the wording of my question. I chose the word deductions as a sloppy translation from German, were you informally say that you deduct certain things, like children/spouse/house/...